# Perform multiple UserRole check

Tags: angular, jwt

I need the `UserComponent` to be accessed for Users with a UserRole of either `1 or 2`. It is shown in the *`AppRoutingModule`* code as (`data : [1,2]}`).

From the `CanActivateGuard` Service how am I suppose to perform this check to allow users with `UserRole` 1 or 2. At the moment I have the code as `this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken("").role === router.data`. But. I need to check if both UserRoles (1 and 2) are allowed.

**AppRoutingModule**

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
   {path:"user" , component:UserComponent, canActivate:[CanActivateGuard], data : [1,2]},
    ...

];
```

**CanActivateGuard**

```ts
canActivate(router : ActivatedRouteSnapshot) :boolean
{  
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token") ? localStorage.getItem("token"): null;

    if ( this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken("token").role === router.data )
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to proceed, staying close to your logic and using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) you can do something like:

```ts
canActivate(router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean 
{  
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token") ? localStorage.getItem("token") : null;

    // You can do this additional check to avoid a null pointer exception below
    if (token === null) return false;

    // If the decoded token has a role of 1 or 2, it will pass this check
    if (router.data.includes(this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken(token).role))
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```